# Add new row after specified number of columns added javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I've been working in getting a dashboard with buttons, each button will represent one machine. This buttons are generated depending on the Jquery results.

Currently, I would like to have 10 buttons added in one row, and then to continue adding them in a new row. Also, my other issue is that I want to change the button color depending on the result of the ajax.

I've tried the following code, but it is giving me as a result the image that I've attached below.

IMAGE:  http://i68.tinypic.com/296oysw.png

(Sorry, couldn't post the image since I'm new to Stackoverflow)

```
  $( document ).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var now = d.getTime() + 300;
    var color;
    var u = '/read/machines/' +{{userid}};
    $.ajax({
      url: u,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {    
          if (item.lastCommunication > now ){
             color = "success";
            }else{
              color = "warning";
            }
            if (i != 0 && i%10 == 0){
               $('<tr>').append(
                 $('<td>').append(
                   $('<button type="info" id="info" class="btn btn-'+color +' btn-lg" ontouchstart="touchAvailable=true; machineInfo('+item.id +');" onclick="if(!touchAvailable) machineInfo('+item.id +');">'+item.name+'</button>')
                       )
                     ).appendTo('#body');  
            }else{
             $('<td>').append(
                  $('<button type="info" id="info" class="btn btn-'+color +' btn-lg" ontouchstart="touchAvailable=true; machineInfo('+item.id +');" onclick="if(!touchAvailable) machineInfo('+item.id +');">'+item.name+'</button>')
                   ).appendTo('#body');
           }
         });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `td` element in the else branch show be append to `#body tr:last`

```
if(i%10 == 0){
 $('<tr>').appendTo('#body');
}

$('<td>').append(BUTTON_CODE).appendTo('#body tr:last');
```

Comment: Amow thanks for your reply, just tried that but I got this as a result:

http://i68.tinypic.com/2el86j5.png

Comment: if you dont have first tr in your #body initially, you should change the code

Comment: you were totally right! now it is showing up just 10 buttons per row, however, it is adding twice the button that goes in the new row like this : http://i67.tinypic.com/2ngrdbc.png . Also, do you know why it is not taking the color depending on the values from `lastCommunication` in the JQuery ?

Comment: If you use the code in my answer, and the twice button you refer to is `computer` of the second row.I think the return data from ajax just have two computer. Not your coding error.And the color problem i also suggest you confirm the ajax return first.

Comment: In your color control code I found that the item will be `success` if its lastCommunication is greater than now? Is it possible?

Comment: I just checked in my DB and there's just one machine with the name "Computer" so I think that maybe there's something that is causing it to be showing up twice, but I can't figure it out. And no, lastCommunication can be either less than now+60 or equal to it. I think you just made me realize of another of my mistakes .

Comment: @natilas12 could you change the code in your question to the newest, so I can help you with the twice button problem

Comment: Amow, I was able to fix the issue with "Computer" showing up twice. Thank you so very much, you were such a great help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try creating row first....when you get to tenth item or last item append row and create new row (if needed)

```
var $tr =$('<tr>')
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    if (item.lastCommunication > now ){
        color = "success";
    }else{
        color = "warning";
    }
    if (i != 0 && i%10 == 0 || i==data.length-1){
        // 10th button or last button append row
        $tr.append(
                $('<td>').append(
                        $('<button type="info" id="info" class="btn btn-'+color +' btn-lg" ontouchstart="touchAvailable=true; machineInfo('+item.id +');" onclick="if(!touchAvailable) machineInfo('+item.id +');">'+item.name+'</button>')
                )
        ).appendTo('#body');
        //create new row
        if(i !== data.length-1){
          $tr =$('<tr>');
        }  
    }else{
        $('<td>').append(
                $('<button type="info" id="info" class="btn btn-'+color +' btn-lg" ontouchstart="touchAvailable=true; machineInfo('+item.id +');" onclick="if(!touchAvailable) machineInfo('+item.id +');">'+item.name+'</button>')
        ).appendTo($tr);
    }
});
```